# Use Python to run interactive python scripts

Tags: python, interactive

I have Python script that takes a User input during runtime and gives some outputs. 
Example code:

```
import random
l1 = ['Bob', 'Eric', 'Dimitar', 'Kyle']
l2 = ['Scott', 'Mat', 'Con']
n = raw_input('Enter no. of persons:  ')
for i in range(int(n)):
    print random.choice(l1) + '  ' + random.choice(l2)
```

Output:

```
$ ./generate_name.py 
Enter no. of persons:  2
Kyle  Scott
Eric  Mat
```

Now I want to write another Python script that would run the first python script multiple times with a specific input (the input sequence is stored in a list) and record the outputs in file.
Moreover, I can't make any changes in the first Python Code.

I can use the `subprocess` module to run the script and record the output but how do I take care of the interactive User input part?

Comment: If you are using a Unix-style system you might use pipes...

Comment: Do you Mean something like:  `subprocess.Popen('./generate_name.py <<< 2', shell= 1)` . Yes that would work. Thanks  a lot :)

Comment: You should probably be using the `stdin` argument to `Popen` rather than ever using `shell=True` (or your less idiomatic version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options: you can either run it as a separate process and indeed use `subprocess`, such as

```
sp = subprocess.Popen(['./generate_name.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sp.stdin.write("2\n")
sp.stdin.close()
answer = sp.stdout.read()
status = sp.wait()
```

or you take your script and `exec` it. Before you do so, you can redirect `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` and you can capture and monitor all changes you make. This way, you can run it inside one process.

Answer (score 0):

First, see [execute python script multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133294/execute-python-script-multiple-times) and [running script multiple times simultaniously in python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840550/running-script-multiple-times-simultaniously-in-python-2-7). Alse, see [run multiple Python scripts from a single parent script](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/36772).